# when to use がつ or げつ readings for 月？

Tags: readings

I am trying to learn the readings for various words that include 月, and am having a hard time remembering when to use がつ or げつ for the on'yomi readings.

The month names, 一月、二月、etc all use がつ, as far as I can tell.
何月 uses がつ, but 毎月 uses the げつ reading.  Is there a pattern or principle governing which reading is used, or is this a matter of rote memory?

Comment: Just so you and others are aware, we rarely if ever use the reading まいげつ for 毎月, instead opting for まいつき.

Comment: There is a ひとつき reading for 一月. It refers to a duration of one month, rather than to January. How you would know is from the sentence and the grammar. Like あの町で一月位泊まった。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When referring to a particular month, (January, February and so on) it reads **がつ** as you mentioned:

> 一月【いちがつ】 January
>   二月【にがつ】 February
>   三月【さんがつ】 March
>   四月【しがつ】 April
>   五月【ごがつ】 May
>   六月【ろくがつ】 June
>   七月【しちがつ】 July
>   八月【はちがつ】 August
>   九月【くがつ】 September
>   十月【じゅうがつ】 October
>   十一月【じゅういちがつ】 November
>   十二月【じゅうにがつ】 December
>   何月【なんがつ】 What month

However, when counting periods of time that span months, it is read **げつ**:

> 一ヶ【いっか】月【げつ】 One month
>   二ヶ【にか】月【げつ】 Two months
>   三ヶ【さんか】月【げつ】 Three months
>   四ヶ【よんか】月【げつ】 Four months
>   五ヶ【ごか】月【げつ】 Five months
>   六ヶ【ろっか】月【げつ】 Six months
>   七ヶ【ななか】月【げつ】 Seven months
>   八ヶ【はっか】月【げつ】 Eight months
>   九ヶ【きゅうか】月【げつ】 Nine months
>   十ヶ【じゅっか】月【げつ】 Ten months
>   十一ヶ【じゅういっか】月【げつ】 Eleven months
>   十二ヶ【じゅうにか】月【げつ】 Twelve months
>   何ヶ【なんか】月【げつ】 How many months

Note that the small 「ヶ」 is read 「か」.

For the rest of words that use 月, I don't know if there's a rule. In general, I just memorise the reading for each word outright.

Comment: 来[月]{げつ} breaks that pattern unfortunately... :-(

Comment: For what is worth, there are far more compound words where 月 reads げつ (**32**) than words where 月 reads がつ (**2 or fewer**, as がつ appears as an alternative reading for those 2 entries) according to jisho.org. See it here: [月 げつ](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%9C%88%20%E3%81%92%E3%81%A4%20%23words?page=2), [月 がつ](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%9C%88%20%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A4%20%23words).

Comment: Also note that there are many entries where [月 reads つき](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%9C%88%20%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8D%20%23words) (65). Some of them refer to the Moon, which is read つき as a word, but there are compound words related to the idea of month that read つき as well, such as 月初【つきはじ】め (beginning of month).